# Loop through an object in a page, if page contains key, append value

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

I have a page full of links. I want to put a little jquery at the bottom that looks for particular URL's or and for each one, append a little tag at the bottom of the page if it finds that URL in the content or if the current page's canonical link (which is included in the meta) matches. So far I have this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var obj = {
    "apple.php":"apple_pixel_url",
    "banana.php":"banana_pixel_url",
    "carrot.php":"carrot_pixel_url"
};

$.each( obj, function( key, value ) {
    $( "html:contains(key)" ).append('<img src="'+value+'">');
});
</script>
```

This always appends all three values, so I'm obviously doing something wrong. I guess Ideally I would look at only "a" links plus any tags that matched

```
<link rel="canonical" href="CANONICAL_URL" />
```

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: what if a page has multiple similar URLs, like `apple.php` ?

Comment: In that case I only want it appended once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also append to the individual links using this syntax:

```
$("a[href$='"+key+"']").append('<img src="'+value+'">');
```

Comment: Definitely a better approach for the problem.

Comment: I don't want to append to the links though, I want to append to the body.

Comment: I want to append to the body or to html. Otherwise this would work fine. How do I append to the end of the page rather than to the matching A tag?

Comment: Do you only need to do this for the first instance of the link? Or for all instances of the link? For example, if the apple.com link shows 23 times, does that count as one for the loop? or 23?

Comment: Only once for each link. If a apple.php link shows 20 times, it should only append once.

Comment: `function load(){
  $.each( obj, function( key, value ) {
      if($("a[href$='"+key+"']").length > 0){
       $("body").append("<img src='"+value+"'/>");
      };
  });
}`

Answer (score 2):

You are passing a static string as selector where as 'key' is a variable.

```
   $( "html:contains("+key+")" ).append('<img src="'+value+'">');
```

Comment: Oh so it was a positive everytime because it was being parsed as "", that makes sense!

Answer (score 1):

It always appends the three links because it's finding the values in your javascript! Check only in the `href` attribute of `<a>` and `<link>` elements.

```
var obj = {
    "apple.php":"apple_pixel_url",
    "banana.php":"banana_pixel_url",
    "carrot.php":"carrot_pixel_url"
};
function load(){
  $.each( obj, function( key, value ) {
    if($("a[href='"+key+"'],link[href='"+key+"']").length > 0){
      $("body").append('<img src="'+value+'">');
    }
  });
}
```

---

```
<body onload="load()">
   <a href="apple.php">Apple</a>
   <link href="carrot.php" />
</body>
```

Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/wjdo23kr/1/

Comment: The problem with that is that the canonical link tag is in the head.

Comment: @pg. Updated answer for complete solution.